# what is the best practice of changing base object properties from inherited class

Tags: c#, .net

I want to set "person" properties of student1 to person1. Is this possible doing it with assigning or any way without setting properties one by one ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var student1 = new Student {Id = 1, Name = "kaya", Class = "3b", Number = "156"};
            var person1 = new Person { Id = 2, Name = "hasan" };

        }


    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student : Person
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public String Class { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Considering the number of ways to go about this you may want to add information about the context in which you are trying to do this.

Why the copy is needed, for what purpose, etc. That way people can give solution that's best for the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you *could* do it with reflection - but I personally wouldn't. You could add a `CopyTo` method in `Person`:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public void CopyTo(Person other)
    {
        other.Id = Id;
        other.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

Another option would be to use composition instead of inheritance, such that a `Student` had a `Person` property instead of deriving from `Person`. It really depends on the bigger picture though - do you actually want a `Student` to be a specialized `Person`, or was it just a simple way of getting the data in there?

This sort of question comes up every so often, but I rarely find myself wanting to do it in my own code... I'd be interested to see the design of code which requires this, to work out how I'd have designed it instead. It's not clear to me whether this is just a matter of me not doing the kind of work which encourages this pattern, or whether I use alternative designs to solve the same problem.

Comment: Jon, I have a feeling there are many more properties involved and Sessiz does not want to manually "connect the dots".

Comment: @Kris: That makes the argument for composition even stronger, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at AutoMapper?  If you used half way decent conventions you end up writing almost zero code -

http://automapper.codeplex.com/

I recently used AutoMapper to map my POCOs with Subsonic.